# How to create a python script that handles an input string or an input file?

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to make a python script that can either process a string fed into the command line

`python my_script.py "Hello World"`

or a set of strings inside a file (e.g. input_file.txt)

`python my_script.py -i input_file.txt`

Is there a way to do this via `argparse`? So far I can handle input files, but I don't know how to add the option of just processing a string fed directly in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make argparse accept one positional argument (filename or string) and one flag (-i). If the flag is present, treat the argument as a file. Take a look at [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments) for more info. I've modified the example to fit your needs.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inp", help="input string or input file")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--treat-as-file", action="store_true",
                    help="reads from file if specified")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.treat_as_file:
    print("Treating {} as input file".format(args.inp))
else:
    print("Treating {} as the input".format(args.inp))
```

Output:

```
/tmp $ python test.py abcde
Treating abcde as the input
/tmp $ python test.py -i abcde
Treating abcde as input file
```

Comment: Great! The ```action="store_true"``` bit is what I needed to make it work. Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

To process a command line string, you can use `sys.argv`, which is a list of all the arguments fed into the command line.

main.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Running the following line in the CLI

`>> python main.py foo bar "hello world"`

would output:

`['main.py', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello world']`